locking shared objects in a multi-threaded environment
The documentation here: https://1973.beastdocs.prtest.cppalliance.org/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream.html
states

Sharedobjects:Unsafe. The application must also ensure that all asynchronous operations are performed within the same implicit or explicit strand.

We are using the older io_service. In this case, would it be okay if I instead simply synchronize access to the shared object using a mutex and lock guards? Under the lock, it may be necessary to perform async operations like async_write.

Asynchronous operations outlive your lock spans.
The only way to reliably synchronize across async operations is by using (implicit) strands.
Note that io_service is literally an alias for io_context only if BOOST_ASIO_NO_DEPRECATED is not set. So, nothing about that changes a thing.
However, you might not need any explicit strands if there's only 1 thread. That thread automatically becomes the implicit strand. Note that there are other ways to get "logical strands" by linear chaining of handlers, but we digress. See this excellent answer for more ideas and illustrations explaining strands: Why do I need strand per connection when using boost::asio?

"Asynchronous operations outlive your lock spans". Could you please elaborate on this? We have one shared object, which only locks on a function-level, and may perform some asynchronous operations (through the top-level boost::asio::post facility).

I'll elaborate when it is clearer what you're trying to achieve. You merely said "Under the lock, it may be necessary to perform async operations like async_write" - which is, in all reasonable interpretations, not possible. Of course, the relationship between your mutex and the (async) operations is key: we don't know anything about it. If you have a link to some more code I'll be happy to give it a look, or maybe just include a self-contained example in the question.

It's essentially this: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/chat-multi/ . I'm curious if I have the shared_state between websocket_session, then I need strand, or lock is sufficient. I think lock is sufficient, since no two threads would write the same socket at once.

It depends only on what is synchronized by the mutex. If it's non-session stuff (so nothing about the async operations uses the shared_state) then indeed, as the linked example shows, you can use classic thread synchronization. The answer, then, was in your link.

They also use strand, so I'm unsure whether it's explicitly necessary, since in our implementation, we do not. It seems that the shared_state uses async_* operations internally, which is what I meant.

They serve different purposes. The strand is there to protect session state related to IO operations (streams, sockets, buffers etc.). The mutex is there to get exclusive access to the shared_state. Yes, the strand is explicitly necessary for the reasons explained in the linked answer: there are multiple threads involved in the io service and the session is full duplex, where send can be called from any thread (e.g. websocket_session.cpp)

Thank you for your answer. As one final clarification, does this mean the strand is necessary in particular because 'websocket' is full-duplex, but for something like 'http' (half-duplex), it may not be necessary?

Again, I'll refer to the linked answer. But yeah, in general, full-duplex always requires a (implicit or explicit) strand, half-duplex may or may not depending on /other interactions/.
